# How can you pass a variable into another class in REACT?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two classes in my code and the other one should pass a variable to another one. I have a variable called state and I have stored this.state.item to it and tried the following code to pass it to another class.

I have put console.log(this.props.state); to that other class in order to find out if something happens there when props should be there and nothing happens. When the code renders for first time "undefined" comes to console but when the contents should appear there again (I have a form where the contents of the variable comes from as an array) nothing comes to the console so apparentally nothing is sent to that other class anymore after the first time?

`<List state={Form.state} />`

I have the constructor in the class where the variable should go.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
}
```

This is how I try to check if the content of the variable comes there.

```
console.log(this.props.state);
```

Comment: Can you show your complete code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`State` is a reserved variable in react components and you cant use it to pass props directly to it. Try passing the value to a variable with another name. Also, you can't use `Form.state`. Use `this.state`

```
<List varname={this.state} />
```